# Rendering a django dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I'm trying to display this aggregate dictionary in my template but it's not working for me. All I want is the total number but I get {'total_sum': 50} and I just want the 50. Where am I going wrong?

```
listcart = cart.objects.filter(sessionid=session)

totals = listcart.aggregate(Sum('total'))


return render_to_response("choosecomp.html",locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request,{'totals':totals}))
```

template:

```
{{totals}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to achieve the desired result would be to get the value using "dot notation" in the template:

```
{{ totals.total__sum }}
```

Also, you can get the actual value in the view:

```
totals = listcart.aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum']
```

Note the two underscores between the `total` and `sum`: `total__sum`.

Comment: So this WHOLE time the two underscores has been what was really killing me. I've tried everything but that. Django can be really frustrating sometimes. Thank you so much, I used the second one, it works perfectly.

Comment: @user3525985 Glad it helped. Yeah, aggregation is not a simple thing. Django tries to makes it easier to understand by having great and informative docs. I suggest going through [`Aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) docs just to be more confident in the topic.

Comment: I did! , I'm went from that to looking for ways to display dictionaries and only got more confused. In time though, I've only been at it for a week or so.